# Keeping Child Branch up to Date with Parent when using commit --amend

Tags: git

My current Git repo has three branches: `mainline`, `feature_a`, and `feature_b`. The history is as follows:

1. `mainline` was cloned from a remote repo
2. `feature_a` branch was checked out from `mainline`
3. Changes were made on `feature_a` and committed as `commit_a`
4. `feature_b` branch was checked out from `feature_a`
5. Changes were made on `feature_b` and committed as `commit_b`
6. Changes were made to `feature_a` and amended to `commit_a`

How do I update the `feature_b` branch with the changes amended to `commit_a`?

Comment: Change to feature_b branch and do `git rebase`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your history probably looks something like this:

```
           A' [feature_a]
          /
*--*--*--* [mainline]
          \
           A [original feature_a]
            \
             B [feature_b]
```

Commit `A` is the original commit you made on `feature_a`. When you amended the commit with `git commit --amend`, it created a *new* commit, `A'`.

You'll need to rebase `feature_b` to attach it to the new commit `A'`. Do:

```
git rebase --onto feature_a A feature_b
```

(You *might* also be able to get away with simply doing `git rebase feature_a feature_b`, but I'm not sure how this will work since you amended commit `A`.)

Now your history will look like this:

```
             B' [feature_b]
            /
           A' [feature_a]
          /
*--*--*--* [mainline]
```

Technically commits `A` and `B` are still in the repo, but since they aren't being used, Git will garbage-collect them later.

Answer (score -1):

Either:

- Check out to `feature_b`, then `git merge feature_a`.

OR:

- Check out to `feature_a`, then `git rebase feature_b`.

Also, why are you amending a commit instead of creating a new one? Generally it is best practice to just create a new commit. However, if you are interested in maintaining a specific storyline of history with your commits, the rebase option above is probably more favorable.

Just be careful with `git commit --amend` or `git rebase` if you are using this repository collaboratively, as both of those commands edit commit ID history and could really mess up your collaborators.

Comment: I hope people who downvote an answer, also say why here!